# How to replicate RDS Aurora Mysql database to an other instance of RDS with just some rows

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a RDS Mysql database instance on AWS with 1000 tables (lets call it root instance).

I need to create another instance of this database with only the rows that match some foreign key id. This new instance must be in mirror with the root instance so I can query the new values as soon as they get inserted. Question: Is there any way to achieve this with AWS tools? Or do I need to code id?

As far as I know, I can create instances in a cluster to be mirrored with the root instance, but these instances are a full copy and I need only some rows.

Answer (score 1):

Neither AWS nor MySQL provide a solution for what you describe.

You would have to develop your own solution. For example a CDC (change data capture) client ([Debezium](https://debezium.io) is a popular open-source CDC implementation) to parse the binary logs of your RDS instance, filter for the rows you want, and insert them to the other instance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with RDS.

You can "fake it" by converting the tables you don't want replicated to Engine=Blackhole, however you have to edit your parameter-group and set "read-only" to 0, instead of the default "{TrueIfReplica}".

and to handle your case you can create a view that pulls only these records

Alternately, you would need to run your own slave server on EC2 with the RDS server as the master (this is possible if you're running MySQL 5.6 on RDS, but not 5.5 or below), however it's extremely complicated to set up.